# A version of Borel-Cantelli lemma without independence

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mathbb P)$ be a probability space and $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of measurable sets with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb P(A_n)=\infty$. I learnt from a talk that there is a version of Borel-Cantelli lemma saying that

$$\mathbb P(\limsup_{N\to \infty} A_N)\ge \limsup_{N\to \infty} \frac{(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\mathbb P(A_n))^2}{\sum \sum_{m,n\le N} \mathbb P(A_m\cap A_n)}.$$

Are there any references for the proof this version of Borel-Cantelli lemma? (or a direct proof if it is not too complicated?)

---

Let me just copy the proof given by saz (thanks!) from the link below just for the convenience of future readers.

Let consider the following application of Cauchy-Schwartz inequality: Let $X_n=1_{A_n}$ for each $n$.

$$\mathbb [E(\sum_{n=1}^{N} X_n)]^2=[E((\sum_{n=1}^{N} X_n) \cdot(1_{\cup_{n=1}^{N} A_n}))]^2 \le E(1_{\cup_{n=1}^{N} A_n})^2 E(\sum_{n=1}^NX_n)^2= \mathbb P(\cup_{n=1}^{N} A_n) {\sum_{m,n\le N} \mathbb P(A_m\cap A_n)}$$

This gives us the Chung-Erdos inequality:

$$ \mathbb P(\cup_{n=1}^{N} A_n) \ge \frac{(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\mathbb P(A_n))^2}{\sum \sum_{m,n\le N} \mathbb P(A_m\cap A_n)}$$

Now one can apply the above inequality to the (truncated) tail union and use the hypothesis to get the inequality we want to prove.

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-35513-7_7)